# In Multi-dimensional array products, how do I align axes with and without summation?

Tags: numpy, scipy, lapack, intel-mkl, numpy-einsum

What is the best way to do array operations when there are some repeated indices which are summed over AND others which are not?  It seems like I may have to use `einsum` for these operations, but it would be better if there was a `tensordot` alternative with a flag for dimensions that are aligned but not summed.

Does anybody know of a fast numerical routine (in lapack perhaps?) that behaves like tensordot, except that some axes can be aligned without being summed?

==

Here is an example code to show type of array operation that is needed.  The operation I need is done by `method_sum`, `method_einsum`, and `method_matmul`.  A similar operation sums over the matching j-axis and is done by `method2_einsum` and `method2_tensordot`.

By comparing times it seems that `tensordot` should be able to beat `einsum` on the first problem.  However, it does not have the functionality to align axes without summing them up.

```
#import scipy
import scipy as sp

# Shapes of arrays
I = 200
J = 50
K = 200
L = 100

a = sp.ones((I, J, L))
b = sp.ones((J, K, L))


# The desired product has a sum over the l-axis

## Use broadcasting to multiply and sum over the last dimension
def method_sum(a, b):
    "Multiply arrays and sum over last dimension."   
    c = (a[:, :, None, :] * b[None, :, :, :]).sum(-1)
    return c

## Use einsum to multiply arrays and sum over the l-axis
def method_einsum(a, b):
    "Multiply arrays and sum over last dimension."
    c = sp.einsum('ijl,jkl->ijk', a, b)
    return c

## Use matmul to multiply arrays and sum over one of the axes
def method_matmul(a, b):
    "Multiply arrays using the new matmul operation."
    c = sp.matmul(a[:, :, None, None, :], 
                  b[None, :, :, :, None])[:, :, :, 0, 0]
    return c


# Compare einsum vs tensordot on summation over j and l

## Einsum takes about the same amount of time when j is not summed over) 
def method2_einsum(a, b):
    "Multiply arrays and sum over last dimension."
    c = sp.einsum('ijl,jkl->ik', a, b)
    return c

## Tensor dot can do this faster but it always sums over the aligned axes
def method2_tensordot(a, b):
    "Multiply and sum over all overlapping dimensions."
    c = sp.tensordot(a, b, axes=[(1, 2,), (0, 2,)])
    return c
```

Here are some times for the various routines on my computer.  Tensordot can beat einsum for `method2` because it uses multiple cores.  I would like to achieve performance like `tensordot` for the calculation where both the J and L-axes are aligned, but only the L-axis is summed.

```
Time for method_sum:
1 loops, best of 3: 744 ms per loop

Time for method_einsum:
10 loops, best of 3: 95.1 ms per loop

Time for method_matmul:
10 loops, best of 3: 93.8 ms per loop

Time for method2_einsum:
10 loops, best of 3: 90.4 ms per loop

Time for method2_tensordot:
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Tensordot works by transposing and reshaping so the problem turns into a `dot`.  Another recent tool is `matmul`, `@`.

Comment: I see.  That would make it impossible to align certain axes without carrying out the sum.  So is there no (performance) equivalent to `tensordot` which allows for axes to be aligned without sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [85]: I,J,K,L=2,3,4,5
In [86]: a=np.ones((I,J,L))
In [87]: b=np.ones((J,K,L))

In [88]: np.einsum('ijl,jkl->ijk',a,b).shape
Out[88]: (2, 3, 4)
```

Playing around with the new `@` operator, I find I can produce:

```
In [91]: (a[:,:,None,None,:]@b[None,:,:,:,None]).shape
Out[91]: (2, 3, 4, 1, 1)

In [93]: (a[:,:,None,None,:]@b[None,:,:,:,None])[...,0,0].shape
Out[93]: (2, 3, 4)
```

The shapes are right, but I haven't checked the values.  Some of the `None` line up the `ijk` axes, and two produce the regular `dot` behavior (last axis with 2nd to the last).

With your sizes the times are about the same:

```
In [97]: np.einsum('ijl,jkl->ijk',a,b).shape
Out[97]: (200, 50, 200)
In [98]: (a[:,:,None,None,:]@b[None,:,:,:,None])[...,0,0].shape
Out[98]: (200, 50, 200)
In [99]: timeit np.einsum('ijl,jkl->ijk',a,b).shape
1 loop, best of 3: 2 s per loop
In [100]: timeit (a[:,:,None,None,:]@b[None,:,:,:,None])[...,0,0].shape
1 loop, best of 3: 2.06 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj!  I have not used `matmul` much, but I definitely see how it has a place for certain calculations.  I notice that, like `einsum` it doesn't create a large temporary array.  But for some reason it still seems to be operating slower than `tensordot`.